# When updating lubuntu 16.04 screen went bad

Tags: lubuntu

I software updated a fresh nice well preformed install of lubuntu 16.04 on a LG x110 pc and the screen went bad just like this example:

- [Upon upgrade of lubuntu 17.10 from 17.04 display messed up on an eeepc 900a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400177/upon-upgrade-of-lubuntu-17-10-from-17-04-display-messed-up-on-an-eeepc-900a)

I think it must be a newer linux cernel or some thing alike. It would be nice to have update alerts just as linux mint does. I have tried to install the newest lubuntu 17 but this version messes it up from the very beginning. 
I have tried the antiX-17.1 distro and it works fine.

Maybe it could be a screen driver. Does any know witch update to avoid?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the messed up screen?

Comment: Sorry but I have just made a clean install on this pc. The screen looks just like this example : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400177/upon-upgrade-of-lubuntu-17-10-from-17-04-display-messed-up-on-an-eeepc-900a
He has the same problem.
I have tried to connect an external screen to this LG X110 and on that external screen it works fine.